# Custom post type hierarchical permalinks not behaving as expected for parent/child pages

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, hierarchical, child-pages

When you have Pages with children, the permalink structure works something like this:

> example.com/parent-page/child-page/

All well and good. Trying to go to this URL:

> example.com/child-page/

doesn't work, which is good, and as expected - I only want the one URL for my child page.

However, I've set up a custom post type, and set it to be hierarchical, so as to behave like pages. It doesn't quite work the same way:

> example.com/custom-post-type/parent-page/child-page/

works as expected, but removing the parent page from the URL:

> example.com/custom-post-type/child-page/

also displays the child page. It should 404, I would have thought.

I've used the following args to register_post_type:

```
$args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui' => true, 
    'show_in_menu' => true, 
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array('slug'=>'custom-post-type','with_front'=>false),
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'has_archive' => false, 
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'menu_position' => null,
    'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail','excerpt','revisions','page-attributes')
);
```

It's entirely possible I've misunderstood some of the options though. Can someone tell me if I'm doing something wrong, or if this is a bug or a feature?

I'm using 3.2.1, with no plugins, just my custom theme.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the answer to this problem by doing this:

`echo get_permalink( $page->ID );`

This gave me the right links to the pages.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> example.com/custom-post-type/parent-page-1/child-page/
> example.com/custom-post-type/parent-page-2/child-page/
> ```

The above could not happen. If you were to give 2 pages the same name (regardless of their parents being different) then WP would amend the slug of one of them.

> ```
> example.com/custom-post-type/parent-page-1/child-page/
> example.com/custom-post-type/parent-page-2/child-page-1/
> ```

Entering `example.com/custom-post-type/child-page/` or `example.com/custom-post-type/child-page-1/` would work as expected, but I believe that `example.com/custom-post-type/parent-page-2/child-page/` would redirect you to `example.com/custom-post-type/parent-page-1/child-page/` (although I am not 100% on that).

Comment: That's not the way it's working for me. I'm using 3.2.1 (should have mentioned that, will edit my main post to put it in), and can have **example.com/custom/pagename**, **example.com/custom/parent1/pagename** and **example.com/custom/parent2/pagename** - Wordpress happily creates them all automatically, without me editing the slug.

Comment: From the [WP Codex for Pages → Add New](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages_Add_New_SubPanel) - **Avoid using the same title twice as that will cause problems**. Maybe when adding/editing pages WP doesn't check for a unique slug, but it really should, else you will get all sorts of issues. The title can be the same, but the slug **MUST** be different - it is as unique as the ID.

Comment: I've amended my question, since this point wasn't what I was actually asking, just a way of illustrating the main problem. The duplicate name is easily fixed with a little reorganization, but I'm mostly interested in stopping **example.com/custom/parent/child** being also available at **example.com/custom/child**.

Comment: Id suggest having a look at the rewrite rules - `$wp_rewrite` is the global for that. It is possible to edit them, and probably this is just the default, if undesired, action.

Comment: this does not seem to address the question...